# Sql query to combine 2 diff. column output based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine 2 columns in new column based on conditions. Please check below query. What I tried.

```
SELECT
  `ContactPers`.`contact_persID`,
  `ContactPers`.`persID`,
  `ContactPers`.`contactID`
FROM `bdrplus`.`contact_pers` AS `ContactPers`
WHERE ((`ContactPers`.`persID` = 55) OR (`ContactPers`.`contactID` = 55))
 AND `ContactPers`.`etat` = 1
```

Output:

```
contact_persID  persID  contactID
18              90      55
19              55      56
20              55      61
23              55      67
```

Desired output is something like (Not want 55 in newColumn as it is in WHERE clause, See above query. want to combine persID and contactID based on conditions.)

```
contact_persID  persID  contactID newColumn
18              90      55        90
19              55      56        56
20              55      61        61
23              55      67        67
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the MySql side of this. Here's how I would do it in SQL:

```
SELECT
    `ContactPers`.`contact_persID`,
    `ContactPers`.`persID`,
    `ContactPers`.`contactID`,
    CASE `ContactPers`.`persID`
        WHEN 55 THEN `ContactPers`.`contactID`
        ELSE `ContactPers`.`persID`
    END AS newColumn
FROM `bdrplus`.`contact_pers` AS `ContactPers`
WHERE 55 IN (`ContactPers`.`persID`, `ContactPers`.`contactID`)
AND `ContactPers`.`etat` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement will let you make decisions on a row-by-row basis. There's also an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) statement that's pretty much the same, but I recommend `CASE` because it has wider support (for example Oracle, SQL Server, Teradata, and others):

```
SELECT
  contact_persID,
  persID,
  contactID,
  CASE WHEN contactID = 55 THEN persID ELSE contactID END AS newColumn
FROM dbrplus.contact_pers
WHERE (PersID = 55 OR contactID = 55)
  AND etat = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for FQN in columnnames for single table queries.

```
SELECT
     contact_persID,
     persID,
     contactID,
     CASE persID WHEN 55 THEN contactID ELSE persID END newColumn
FROM
    .......
```